# Why can't add font typeface, MediaPlayer and others in activity extended Fragment

Tags: android

I was wondering why I can added TextView in activity extended Fragment but why I can't add Font Typeface and MediaPlayer in the Activity that extended Fragment.

Based on image bellow, how can I solved the issue. Kindly please advise me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with `Fragments`... 
**`this` keyword is not useful to get `Context` or `Activity`..**

You have to get activity for using these type of functions by using `getActivity()`...

Try This code to get font from asset

```
btn_click = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity() , resId );

typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/customfont.ttf");
```

this may help you...

Comment: yes. `this` returns current instance of class/activity. Fragments are not instantiated. Their activities are. So get the activity associated with them for getting the context.